# Are Angular2's services supposed to be stateless?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I come from Java world where services are commonly meant to be stateless. Should be services in Angular2 also stateless? Or can we simply store the state, because we do not have to care about concurrent thread access as in Java example?

At https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#teach-authguard-to-authenticate in AuthService class the state is stored.

Is it just to simplify the example or is it a common practice? I know that services are instantiated and live for the scope where they are declared, but that would mean that I would have to care where the service has been provided to know how long the state lasts.

Comment: The common practice in Angular2 is services will be injected as singletons, mean it could and should be stateful.

Comment: Don't see why singleton should be automatically supposed to be stateful. In the given example of Java and Spring, Spring's services are also singletons but must remain stateless.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to have components stateless and store the state in a service, especially in components added by the router, so that navigating away and later back to a route, doesn't drop the data.

Therefore to your question:
Services are not supposed to be stateless. They often are, but it's not required.

You can use an [NGRX Store](https://ngrx.io/guide/store) to store the state instead, but that's a service as well.

> I would have to care where the service has been provided to know how long the state lasts.

Yes, that's what you have to do. It's usually quite easy. If you want a service and its state to be available during the whole application lifetime, you provide it in `@NgModule()` (needs some special handling for lazy loaded modules), otherwise you provide it at a component, and the lifetime of the service will end with the component instance being destroyed.

Comment: I've seen an article that says exactly the opposite - services should be stateless (publish events). I could see both points of view, but a service method should be a stateless method in my opinion.

Comment: A link would be interesting to see the arguments. What do you mean with "service method"? As mentioned, you can hold a state outside of the injected service classes, but an rx store would also be injected to a service. I find it hard to draw a line what still is considered a service and what is just a model.

Comment: [Here is the article](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/03/five-ways-to-write-better-angular-services/). I consider a service to be something that does a task, as opposed to a component which generally interacts directly with the user.

Comment: The arguments in the article are good. Concurrent access is less an issue if observables are used properly. It's common in Angular to call everything that **is injected** a service. For you and the article a service seems to be rather something that provides some functionality, like fetching data. I can agree with this point of view. In my answer I assumed "Angular service", perhaps this was to vague.

Comment: What if the component is like a container, which could nest itself? Would the service hold the parent's or child's state?

Comment: @theMayer, that article seems to be in direct opposite of angular documentation: `every component instance has its own injector. Providing the service at the component level ensures that every instance of the component gets its own` https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection