# How to design store (state of app) so we change data in store directly without actions, reducers?

Tags: javascript, angular

**Reason:**  Action introduces huge boilerplate even for simple operation. It makes simple code complicated.

**Goal:** For example

```
interface Contact {
  name: string,
  id: string,
}
interface State {
  c1:Contact;
  c2:Contact;
}
let store: MyStore<State>;

store.operateOn(['c1'],(c:Contact)=>c.name='New name'); //['c1'] denotes path to contact
```

so after `store.operateOn()` execution a true state change will occur and 
 concerned subscriber will be notified.

**Summary:** Is there any ngrx/store like db which let us to change data directly/indirectly without any actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a library to do just this. It's called [`ng-app-state`](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/ng-app-state), and it is a wrapper around `@ngrx/store`. In your example, you would update the store with a command like this:

```
store('c1')('name').set('New name');
```

It also provides a similar interface to observe changes to the store at any level. E.g. to observe all changes to `c1` use

```
store('c1').$.subscribe(...);
```

To achieve this, you define the MyStore service as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyStore extends AppStore<State> {
  constructor(store: Store<any>) {
    super(store, "myState", new State());
  }
}
```

There of course is a little setup in your app module, as well. Learn more at the GitHub page: https://github.com/simontonsoftware/ng-app-state

Answer (score 0):

You could repurpose an Angular service to be [stateful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378410/are-angular2s-services-supposed-to-be-stateless#42385005). Store/cache whatever you want in there; merge updates however you want. Share one or more instances across your app to coordinate state. I have used this approach in successful production Angular apps.

For a concrete but flexible example, you could mimic the (non-Redux) React [approach](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to state. Store data as a JSON-like object called "state" and issue "setState" requests to merge changes into it, perhaps taking advantage of spread operator.

```
@Injectable()
export class StateService {

  private state = {};

  constructor() {}

  public setState(changes: any): void {
    this.state = {
      ...this.state,
      ...changes,
    };
  }

  public getState(): any {
    return _.cloneDeep(this.state); // or Object.assign, or raw this.state
  }
}
```

Then use that anywhere in your app. Add change listeners if desired.

With a bit more effort, you could implement the interface you described in the question, perhaps leveraging lodash path-based operations. Maybe even share the result as an open-source project. Such a thing may well exist; I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library called ngx-RxCache. Take a look at https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-rxcache. It helps you create Angular services for statemangement with hardly any boilerplate at all.